# Fully responsive DFP ads not working

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, ads, google-dfp

I am trying to create responsive DFP ads for my wordpress site but it doesn't work. I have been using this article:

http://exisweb.net/how-to-use-google-adsense-on-a-responsive-website#comment-220787
(Solution 3)

and
https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3423562?hl=en#

My code for the header section is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function() {
var gads = document.createElement('script');
gads.async = true;
gads.type = 'text/javascript';
var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + 
'//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() {

var mapping1 = googletag.sizeMapping().
addSize([480, 200], [468, 60]).
addSize([768, 200], [728, 90]).
build();

googletag.defineSlot('/4049405/728x90_1_archive_hrreview', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1420018633340-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot('/4049405/728x90_1_home_hrreview', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1420018633340-1').defineSizeMapping(mapping1).addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot('/4049405/728x90_2_home_hrreview', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1420018633340-2').defineSizeMapping(mapping1).addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot('/4049405/728x90_3_home_hrreview', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1420018633340-3').defineSizeMapping(mapping1).addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot('/4049405/728x90_div-analysis_hrreview', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1420018633340-4').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot('/4049405/728x90_div-blogs_hrreview', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1420018633340-5').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot('/4049405/728x90_div-news_hrreview', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1420018633340-6').addService(googletag.pubads());
```

The above changes nothing. I am trying to change the ads in the main content on the left. There should be 2 sizes: 728px x 90px and 468px x 60px. Currently only the larger ad displays. So when you reduce the size of the website the ads sticks out into the right column. And when the website is really small the ad sticks out across the site.

Website: http://www.hrreview.co.uk

Is there something I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

In your adsize functions, the first set of numbers is indicating the viewport dimensions that will be used to determine when an ad with the second dimensions will be used.

In order that the cascade is respected, the larger screen size needs to be at the top.

More in [Google's Responsive Ads docs](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3423562?hl=en).